# Create 3-letter combinations from dictionary including 2-color combinations

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to take an input of a variety of 2-letter combinations from the letters 'WUBRG' and figure out what 3-letter combinations can be made from them, and add them to the dictionary.

Also, the 3-leter combinations can only be one of these: {'WBG', 'RGW', 'GUR', 'WUB', 'URW', 'RWB', 'GWU', 'UBR', 'BGU', 'BRG'}

An example input would be
{'WU': 6, 'WB': 15, 'UB': 12}

And the intended output would be:
{'WU': 6, 'WB': 15, 'UB': 12, 'WUB': 1}

```
def generate_combinations():
    colors = ['W', 'U', 'B', 'R', 'G']
    combinations = [a + b + c for a in colors for b in colors for c in colors]
    return set(combinations)

def find_viable_combinations(input_dict, number):
    output_dict = input_dict.copy()
    three_color_combinations = generate_combinations()

    for combo in three_color_combinations:
        # Check if the combination can be formed using the 2-color combinations in input_dict
        can_form = all(color in input_dict for color in combo)

        if can_form:
            output_dict[combo] = number
    return output_dict
```

This ended up just returning the same thing as inputed.

Comment: write full code

Comment: what is the meaning of `int` value of the dictionary for `input` & `output`? and also what does `number` do in `find_viable_combinations`? you show the output but not how you call the function. `WUB` can be found in 3 different ways, why is 1? what is needed for a `WUB: 2`?

Comment: I would say there aren't **any** three-letter combinations that can be made from a two-letter combination...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit

First of all, your `generate_combinations` function creates 125 combinations (same letters in different order) you can use `combinations` function from `itertools`.

For string combinations, you can use:

```
def generate_combinations():
    colors = "WUBRG"
    combs = list("".join(comb) for comb in combinations(colors, 3))
    return combs
```

This function will return:

```
['WRG', 'URG', 'UBG', 'WUR', 'WBR', 'WUB', 'UBR', 'WBG', 'WUG', 'BRG']
```

---

Then you can check what chars are in the keys of the `input_dict`:

```
def find_viable_combinations(input_dict, number):
    output_dict = input_dict.copy()
    three_color_combinations = generate_combinations()
    
    chars = ''.join({ch 
             for key in input_dict 
             for ch in key})
            
    for combo in three_color_combinations:
        if sorted(combo) == sorted(chars):
            output_dict[combo] = number
    return output_dict
```

The returned dict:

```
{'WU': 6, 'WB': 15, 'UB': 12, 'WUB': 1}
```

### Original Answer Code:

- Used `set` instead of `list` for the combinations.

```
from itertools import combinations

def generate_combinations():
    colors = "WUBRG"
    combs = set("".join(comb) for comb in combinations(colors, 3))
    return combs

def find_viable_combinations(input_dict, number):
    output_dict = input_dict.copy()
    three_color_combinations = generate_combinations()
    print(three_color_combinations)
    chars = {ch 
             for key in input_dict 
             for ch in key}
            
    for combo in three_color_combinations:
        if set(combo) == chars:
            output_dict[combo] = number
    return output_dict
```

---

### Edit 2:

You can use `set.difference` to achieve what you wanted:

```
from itertools import combinations

def generate_combinations():
    colors = "WUBRG"
    combs = set("".join(comb) for comb in combinations(colors, 3))
    return combs

def find_viable_combinations(input_dict, number):
    output_dict = input_dict.copy()
    three_color_combinations = generate_combinations()

    chars = {ch 
             for key in input_dict 
             for ch in key}
            
    for combo in three_color_combinations:
        if not set(combo).difference(chars):
            output_dict[combo] = number
    return output_dict

print(find_viable_combinations({'UB': 6, 'UR': 3, 'UG': 3, 'BR': 7, 'BG': 8, 'RG': 5}, 4))
```

##### Output:

```
{'UB': 6, 'UR': 3, 'UG': 3, 'BR': 7, 'BG': 8, 'RG': 5, 'URG': 4, 'BRG': 4, 'UBR': 4, 'UBG': 4}
```

Comment: why you need `set`? In case wouldn't be better to apply it to `colors` only?

Comment: @cards You are right.. I edited my answer

Comment: @cards by `colors` you mean `chars` right? because `colors` is a string..

Comment: no to the string `colors` directly to prevent combinations with repeated values (in case of a more exotic choice of `'WUBRG'`). I noticed in a second moment that `set` was originally used in the OP

Comment: @cards Yes OP used set in the description, but in the code attached a list was used.. So at first I used a set (according to the description) and then I replaced it with list like the code example..

Comment: Thank you @nokla , this works. However, it does not work when the is more than 3 colors. It worked in the instance I provided, but I could not have it return a valid output with 4 or 5 colors.

When I adjusted my input, it outputs just the 2-color combinations, not three. See this example output:

{'UB': 6, 'UR': 3, 'UG': 3, 'BR': 7, 'BG': 8, 'RG': 5}

I did my best to edit the code, but it just provides the 2-color combination still. Any tips?
https://pastebin.com/H0HwEh0R

Comment: @JakeHenderson I am sorry, I just don't understand what you expect the output to be when you input more than 3 colors, for example:  `{'UB': 6, 'UR': 3, 'UG': 3, 'BR': 7, 'BG': 8, 'RG': 5}`..

Comment: @nokla, each letter reptesents a color. UR is a combinatiom of U and R. UB a combo of U and B. Therefore that example is U,B,R, and G. The viable 3-color combinations would be " GUR, UBR, BGU, and BRG. Does that make sense?

Comment: @JakeHenderson Hey, please look at Edit 2. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @nokla precisely. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The OP is quite confused, in particular the description and the code could mismatch, see my comment to the question.

> figure out what 3-letter combination

I suppose is meant combining together two colours of 2-characters each to make a colour of 3-characters, `WU` & `WB` -> `WUB`
This can be done using `set`-theoretic operations.

> 3-leter combinations can only be one of these [...]

There are `3!**(10 choose 3)=6**10` possible ways to write these 3-colours, they need to be standardize wrt an alphabetic order, using `sort`, and build a mapping. From the previous example `WUB` is a valid 3-colour but not `BUW` or such.

> [there is a certain quite mysterious] `number`

Assuming it refers to the amount of ways 2-colours can be merged to make a valid 3-colour. Use a counter together with the mapping.

Code updated from comments

```
from itertools import combinations


def find_viable_combinations(two_colours, number):
    valid_3colours = 'WBG', 'RGW', 'GUR', 'WUB', 'URW', 'RWB', 'GWU', 'UBR', 'BGU', 'BRG'
    valid_3colours_map = dict(zip(map(''.join, map(sorted, valid_3colours)), valid_3colours))

    output = {}
    for c1, c2 in combinations(two_colours, 2):
        s1 = set(c1)
        u = s1.union(c2)
        if len(u) == 3:
            three_colour = ''.join(sorted(u))
            key = valid_3colours_map.get(three_colour, None)
            if key is None:
                raise Exception('Invalid data')
            if key not in output:
                output[key] = number

    return two_colours | output

out = find_viable_combinations(data, 4)
print(out)
```

Output

```
{'UB': 6, 'UR': 3, 'UG': 3, 'BR': 7, 'BG': 8, 'RG': 5, 'UBR': 4, 'BGU': 4, 'GUR': 4, 'BRG': 4}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is close to what I'm trying to do. A few things: The reason for the int is a placeholder. In the project I'm working on, it will always be on. As for 'WUBRG', those are the only letters used in this project. Finally, the list of 3-colors is the order of those colors are to eliminate duplicates.. As WUB and UBW are redundant. My need is for an input such as "{'UB': 6, 'UR': 3, 'UG': 3, 'BR': 7, 'BG': 8, 'RG': 5}" to have 'UBR': 1, 'BRG':1, and 'WUB':1 added to the dictionary.

Comment: @JakeHenderson How can you have `WUB` added to the dict when there is no `W` at all in the input? It makes no sense.